# Combining multiple csv files in Powershell changes format

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm attempting to combine numerous csv files into a single outfile. It works okay in that the files are combined, however it changes the format of the outfile by making every line from the input files as a single value that just happens to contain commas. In other words, I get "1,2,3" in a single cell instead of "1" "2" "3" each in their own cell.

`Get-Content C:\RollingLogs\*.csv | Out-File C:\CombinedLogs\outfile.csv`

[Here is a snip from the output file, if that helps to explain what's happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8DNN.png) The desired output is for "1" to be in column A, "2" in column B, etc. Instead we wind up with "1,2,3" all in column A.

I've tried specifying the comma as a delimiter with Out-File, but just makes everything a new line instead of keeping them in proper rows, which is worse. I also tried `gc *.csv | Export-Csv outfile.csv` but it just hangs without doing anything. Export-csv also changes the contents (1,2,3 from the input becomes "#TYPE System.Int32" and I don't know why). I have wondered if `Import-Csv file1.csv | Export-Csv -Append outfile.csv` might work, but since there are multiple input files it would require a foreach loop (I think?) and I have no idea how to do that.

Edit: Contents of the input file as seen in Notepad, to see delimiters

TCP,svchost.exe,1404,LISTENING
TCP,System,4,LISTENING
TCP,System,4,LISTENING

There are line breaks after the G, but they don't show up in StackOverflow without editing it more.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem C:\RollingLogs\*.csv | Import-Csv | Export-Csv dest.csv -NoType`

Comment: Unfortunately that throws an error.

PS C:\RollingLogs> Get-ChildItem C:\RollingLogs\*.csv | Import-Csv |Export-Csv dest.csv -NoType

***Import-Csv : You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both.
At line:1 char:38
+ Get-ChildItem *.csv | Import-Csv |Export-Csv test.csv -NoType
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-Csv], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotSpecifyPathAndLiteralPath,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand***
I tried the full path and .\ but neither worked

Comment: You're missing a backslash between `C:\RollingLogs*.csv` --> `C:\RollingLogs\*.csv` or you might use named parameters: `... -path C:\RollingLogs -include *.csv...`

Comment: _"..every line from the input files as a single value that just happens to contain commas."_ would imply you have badly quoted csv files. Did you by any chance first removed all quotes from these files?

Comment: @Theo there are no quotation marks in the input files.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. You have a csv where all necessary quotes have been removed, so now there is no way to know if a comma is a delimiter between fields or part of a field. Question: is the comma actually used as delimiter or does the csv use some other character for that? Please open the csv in notepad, copy the first 3 lines and paste them into your question as formatted text

Comment: @Theo I just updated it with text. Not sure what you mean by formatted, I'm not very familiar with StackOverflow, but it's a clean copy/paste from Notepad. Contents of the file are tcpvcon64.exe with -RedirectStandardOutput target.csv if you want to create a similar file to test with.

Comment: @iRon I double-checked and fixed all of the slashes, but still get the same error.

Comment: `tcpvcon64.exe` has a `-c` switch to output proper CSV. That would surround items that happen to have a comma with quotes

Comment: @Theo I’m using the -c option already. The output from tcpvcon is  fine, the issue occurs when combining them with out-file

Comment: Use `Export-Csv`, not `Out-File`